# How can print table variable values in tsql?

Tags: sql-server

I'm a new in `sql server` and write this `tsql`:

```
DECLARE @TempCustomer TABLE
(
   DATE_ nchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO 
    @TempCustomer 
SELECT distinct [ExecuteDate]
FROM 
     [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills]

DECLARE  @intFlag int
set @intFlag=0;
WHILE (@intFlag <=2)
BEGIN
    PRINT @TempCustomer.DATE_
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

but when i run that query i get this error:

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Must declare the scalar variable "@TempCustomer".
```

How can i solve that problem?thanks all.

Comment: `select * from @TempCustomer`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that show me all data! i want show record by record

Comment: in loop u r  setting @intFlag how does it make difference ithink quetion is not clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you have such a requirement.. you can very well use select * from @tempCustomer as above said in comments.. But if you still want to loop thru and print individual dates the you can do some workaround

```
DECLARE @TempCustomer TABLE
(
   id int identity(1,1)
   DATE_ nchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO 
    @TempCustomer 
SELECT distinct [ExecuteDate]
FROM 
     [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills]

DECLARE  @intFlag int
set @intFlag=0;
WHILE (@intFlag <=2)
BEGIN
    select * from @TempCustomer where id = @intFlag
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

At first change table variable declaration:

```
DECLARE @TempCustomer TABLE (
    RN int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    DATE_ nchar(20)
);
DECLARE  @intFlag int
```

After INSERT use `@@ROWCOUNT` to obtain number of inserted rows:

```
INSERT INTO  @TempCustomer 
SELECT distinct [ExecuteDate]
FROM [GetOnlineBills]

SELECT @intFlag = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Then WHILE loop:

```
WHILE (@intFlag > 0)
BEGIN
    select DATE_
    from @TempCustomer
    WHERE RN = @intFlag

    SET @intFlag = @intFlag - 1
END
```

This solution is a little bit vague, but should work though.